# Tableau - change what measure is used for colour

Tags: tableau-api

I have a map with several nodes. They are colored red-green using a measure.

I would like an interactive panel where the user can choose which measure is being used for the color - so they could choose profitability, number of employees, etc.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you want to color your map using `Dimension_Name1` & `Dimension_Name2`.

- Create a parameter `Color Parm` with

---

```
Data type: String;
Allowable values: List;
Value (in row 1): Dimension_Name1;
Value (in row 2): Dimension_Name2.
```

- Right click on this parameter and select 'Show Parameter Control'
- Create calculated field `Color Parm Filter` with definition

---

```
IF [Color Parm] = 'Dimension_Name1' THEN [Dimension_Name1]
ELSE [Dimension_Name2]
END
```

- Drag it to 'Color' Marks

Voila!

*Don't forget to let us know if it solved your problem :)*